# Mixing tweetnacl.js with TweetNaclFast (java) for asymmetric encryption

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, tweet-nacl

Our project is using asymmetric encryption with `nacl.box` and ephemeral keys:

```
    encrypt(pubKey, msg) {
        if (typeof msg !== 'string') {
            msg = JSON.stringify(msg)
        }
        let ephemKeys = nacl.box.keyPair()
        let msgArr = nacl.util.decodeUTF8(msg)
        let nonce = nacl.randomBytes(nacl.box.nonceLength)
        p(`naclRsa.pubKey=${this.pubKey}`)
        let encrypted = nacl.box(
            msgArr,
            nonce,
            nacl.util.decodeBase64(pubKey),
            ephemKeys.secretKey
        )
        let nonce64 = nacl.util.encodeBase64(nonce)
        let pubKey64 = nacl.util.encodeBase64(ephemKeys.publicKey)
        let encrypted64 = nacl.util.encodeBase64(encrypted)
        return {nonce: nonce64, ephemPubKey: pubKey64, encrypted: encrypted64}
    }
```

We presently have `node.js` apps that then decrypt these messages.  We would like the option to use `jvm` languages for some features.  There does not seem to be the richness of established players for `tweet-nacl` on the `jvm` but it seems

- `tweetnacl-java` https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/tweetnacl-java

and its recommended implementation

° `tweetnacl-fast` https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/tweetnacl-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/iwebpp/crypto/TweetNaclFast.java

were a popular one.

It is unclear what the analog to the `asymmetric` encryption with ephemeral keys were in that library. Is it supported?   Note that I would be open to either `java` or  `kotlin` if this were not supported in `tweetnacl-java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*tweetnacl-java*](https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/tweetnacl-java) is a port of [*tweetnacl-js*](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js). It is therefore to be expected that both provide the same functionality. At least for the posted method this is the case, which can be implemented on the Java side with *TweetNaclFast* as follows:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

import com.iwebpp.crypto.TweetNaclFast;
import com.iwebpp.crypto.TweetNaclFast.Box;
import com.iwebpp.crypto.TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair;

...

private static EncryptedData encrypt(byte[] pubKey, String msg) {
    KeyPair ephemKeys = Box.keyPair();
    byte[] msgArr = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] nonce = TweetNaclFast.randombytes(Box.nonceLength);
    
    Box box = new Box(pubKey, ephemKeys.getSecretKey());
    byte[] encrypted = box.box(msgArr, nonce);
    
    String nonce64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(nonce);
    String ephemPubKey64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ephemKeys.getPublicKey());
    String encrypted64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    return new EncryptedData(nonce64, ephemPubKey64, encrypted64);
}

...

class EncryptedData {
    public EncryptedData(String nonce, String ephemPubKey, String encrypted) {
        this.nonce = nonce;
        this.ephemPubKey = ephemPubKey;
        this.encrypted = encrypted;
    }
    public String nonce;
    public String ephemPubKey;
    public String encrypted;
}
```

---

In order to demonstrate that both sides are compatible, in the following a plaintext is encrypted on the Java side and decrypted on the JavaScript side:

- First, a key pair is needed on the JavaScript side, whose public key (`publicKeyJS`) is passed to the Java side. The key pair on the JavaScript side can be generated as follows:

  ```
  let keysJS = nacl.box.keyPair();
  let secretKeyJS = keysJS.secretKey;
  let publicKeyJS = keysJS.publicKey;
  console.log("Secret key: " + nacl.util.encodeBase64(secretKeyJS));
  console.log("Public key: " + nacl.util.encodeBase64(publicKeyJS));
  ```

  with the following sample output:

  ```
  Secret key: YTxAFmYGm4yV2OP94E4pcD6LSsN4gcSBBAlU105l7hw= 
  Public key: BDXNKDHeq0vILm8oawAGAQtdIsgwethzBTBqmsWI+R8=
  ```
- The encryption on the Java side is then using the `encrypt` method posted above (and `publicKeyJS`):

  ```
  byte[] publicKeyJS = Base64.getDecoder().decode("BDXNKDHeq0vILm8oawAGAQtdIsgwethzBTBqmsWI+R8=");
  EncryptedData encryptedFromJava = encrypt(publicKeyJS, "I've got a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore...");
  System.out.println("Nonce: " + encryptedFromJava.nonce);
  System.out.println("Ephemeral public key: " + encryptedFromJava.ephemPubKey);
  System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + encryptedFromJava.encrypted);
  ```

  with the following sample output:

  ```
  Nonce: FcdzXfYwSbI0nq2WXsLe9aAh94vXSoWd
  Ephemeral public key: Mde+9metwF1jIEij5rlZDHjAStR/pd4BN9p5JbZleSg=
  Ciphertext: hHo7caCxTU+hghcFZFv+djAkSlWKnC12xj82V2R/Iz9GdOMoTzjoCDcz9m/KbRN6i5dkYi3+Gf0YTtKlZQWFooo=
  ```
- The decryption on the JS side gives the original plaintext (using `secretKeyJS`):

  ```js
  let nonce = "FcdzXfYwSbI0nq2WXsLe9aAh94vXSoWd";
  let ephemPubKey = "Mde+9metwF1jIEij5rlZDHjAStR/pd4BN9p5JbZleSg=";
  let encrypted = "hHo7caCxTU+hghcFZFv+djAkSlWKnC12xj82V2R/Iz9GdOMoTzjoCDcz9m/KbRN6i5dkYi3+Gf0YTtKlZQWFooo=";
  let secretKeyJS = nacl.util.decodeBase64("YTxAFmYGm4yV2OP94E4pcD6LSsN4gcSBBAlU105l7hw=");
  let decryptedFromJS = decrypt(secretKeyJS, {nonce: nonce, ephemPubKey: ephemPubKey, encrypted: encrypted});
  console.log(nacl.util.encodeUTF8(decryptedFromJS)); // I've got a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore...
    
  function decrypt(secretKey, ciphertext){
      let decrypted = nacl.box.open(
          nacl.util.decodeBase64(ciphertext.encrypted),
          nacl.util.decodeBase64(ciphertext.nonce),
          nacl.util.decodeBase64(ciphertext.ephemPubKey),
          secretKey
      );
      return decrypted;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl-util@0.15.1/nacl-util.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl@1.0.3/nacl.min.js"></script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My complete code for tweetnacl-java (Kudos to @topaco)

> I generated two random key-pairs and saved their secret keys in the application.properties file, so that, i will always have the same pub&sec along with the nonce.

> KeyPair baseKeyPair= Box.keyPair();
> ***String baseKeyPairSecretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baseKeyPair.getSecretKey());***

> KeyPair ephemeralKeyPair= Box.keyPair();
> ***String ephemeralKeyPairSecretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ephemeralKeyPair.getSecretKey());***

> byte[] nonce = TweetNaclFast.randombytes(Box.nonceLength);
> ***String nonce64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(nonce);***

```
 private final AppConfig config; //you can autowire the config class 

 private TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair getBaseKeyPair() {
        byte[] secretKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(config.getTweetNACLConfig().getBaseSecretKey());
        return TweetNaclFast.Box.keyPair_fromSecretKey(mySecretKey);
    }


    private TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair getEphemeralKeyPair() {
        byte[] secretKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(config.getTweetNACLConfig().getEphemeralSecretKey());
        return TweetNaclFast.Box.keyPair_fromSecretKey(mySecretKey);
    }


    private byte[] getNonce() {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(config.getTweetNACLConfig().getNonce().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public String encrypt(String msg) {
        TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair baseKeyPair = getBaseKeyPair();
        TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair ephemeralKeyPair = getEphemeralKeyPair();
        byte[] msgArr = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] nonce = getNonce();
        TweetNaclFast.Box box = new TweetNaclFast.Box(baseKeyPair.getPublicKey(), ephemeralKeyPair.getSecretKey());
        byte[] encryptedData = box.box(msgArr, nonce);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptData);
    }


    public String decrypt(String encryptedData) {
        TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair baseKeyPair = getBaseKeyPair();
        TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair ephemeralKeyPair = getEphemeralKeyPair();
        byte[] nonce = getNonce();
        TweetNaclFast.Box box = new TweetNaclFast.Box(ephemeralKeyPair.getPublicKey(), baseKeyPair.getSecretKey());
        byte[] boxToOpen = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedData);
        byte[] decryptedData = box.open(boxToOpen, nonce);
        return new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

> Please, note these two lines
> TweetNaclFast.Box box = new TweetNaclFast.Box(baseKeyPair.getPublicKey(), ephemeralKeyPair.getSecretKey());
> TweetNaclFast.Box box = new TweetNaclFast.Box(ephemeralKeyPair.getPublicKey(), baseKeyPair.getSecretKey());

return encryptAndDecryptData.encrypt("Friday"); // JHo/tk/Jpp2rpxpzIIgBhVhK/CBZLg==
return encryptAndDecryptData.decrypt("JHo/tk/Jpp2rpxpzIIgBhVhK/CBZLg==") //Friday
```